# how to sort posts (sort by views) using post_views_count function?

Tags: wordpress

i want to sort posts (sort by views) using this function

i am using this code in function.php to get post views count

```
<?php
function getPostViews($postID){
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    return "0 View";
}
return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    $count = 0;
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
}else{
    $count++;
    update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
}
}
?>
```

like this way

```
 &orderby=comment_count&order=desc
 &v_sortby=views&v_orderby=desc
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this query:

```
$new_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'post_views_count', 'orderby'=> 'meta_value', 'order' => 'desc' ) );
```